# How to enable wireless connection

Tags: wireless

After installing Ubuntu 13.10, my laptop can’t connect to wireless any more. I tried to fix it by following [this thread on LinuxQuestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/wireless-became-disabled-how-do-i-enable-858357/), but it doesn't solve my problem.

This is my output to run the command:

```
sudo rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

I tried to turn on the soft blocked wireless by the command: 
`rfkill unblock all`
but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that

```
rfkill unblock all
```

does not work, check the following

- Is there a hard-ware switch? Some laptops have hardware switch controlling wifi connection.
- Which Connection Manager are you using? Some Connection Managers (such as connman) are not so well documented and they may disable your wifi(or bluetooth) by default.

For connman, config file may be found under /etc/connman/*.conf or /etc/connman.conf.

Comment: My laptop do have the hard-ware switch. However, after installing ubuntu, it doesn't work anymore. Where can I find which connection manager I am using?

Comment: Debian use NetworkManager as default manager, you may found the config file at /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf or /etc/NetworkManager.conf. Also you should make sure your wifi-switch is on and wifi interface is enabled in bios.